# Google Sheets: how to find max value in column B, corresponding values in column A, and max among these

Tags: google

I have two numeric columns, A and B. I want to find the max value in column B, which will return multiple rows. Then I want to find the max value in column A from among these rows.

```
A   B
 5  315
 7  315
10  275
```

The function should return:

```
 7  315
```

It would be fine if this were a combination of two functions - one that finds the max value in B (315), and another that finds the corresponding max value in A (7). That's how I'm trying it right now using:

```
=index(A2:B10,match(max(B2:B10),B2:B10,0))
```

But this solution only finds the *latest* row that has column B's max value:

```
 5  315
```

Someone suggested I use the query function, but I couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have data in the columns `A`, `B` from row `2` to `4`. Put `MAX(B2:B4)` somewhere (in this example, I put it in `B6`). Then for the corresponding max in `A` you can use the formula `MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B4 = $B$6,A2:A4)))`.

Comment: That works! Also, see the method I figured out in my separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out using the query function and referencing a specific cell.

First, as @dcolazin suggests, you put the max of column B in a cell (I chose B1):

```
=max(B2:B10)
```

Then you do this in cell A1 (notice the "&&" to reference a cell within your SQL query):

```
=query(A2:B10,"select max(A) where B >= "&B1&"")
```